# What happened to the Imperial Security Complex after the Battle of Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In Rogue One,

> The Imperial Security Complex is destroyed by an indirect blast from the Death Star, in an attempt to stop the rebels stealing the Death Star plans.

What happened after this (specifically to the remains of the Complex)?

Comment: Assuming the blast was similar to Jeddah, just less direct, I'm pretty sure there wasn't much left for stuff to happen to.

Comment: However, Grand Moff Wilhuff Tarkin ordered the Death Star to fire a precise single reactor blast at the planet, not destroying Scarif itself[8] but dissipating its planetary shield[3] and obliterating the Citadel Tower as well as everyone in its vicinity in an unsuccessful effort to halt the transmission, as well as eliminate his longtime political rival, Orson Krennic.[8]  [8] - The film itself [here's the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtOAx1gjeQM), [3] the Novelisation. Free rep for anyone who wants to write it up.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Basically vaporised or pulverised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Imperial Security Complex was likely rendered **totally uninhabitable** or usable. After consulting the story arc "The Ashes of Jedha" from the canon comic book *Star Wars*, one can see that the moon Jedha was left essentially unfit to live in, as demonstrated by this panel: [image]

Mind you, this is from a single reactor ignition, the same type that was used on Scarif. Logically one can assume that the Imperial security complex and everything around it were left as nothing but a humongous crater. So far we know nothing about the Empire possibly returning there, but there would be no remnants of the complex to find.

> Information comes courtesy of [*Star Wars Book IX: The Ashes of Jedha*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Book_IX:_The_Ashes_of_Jedha)